# Mark error in form using Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've started using Bootstrap in order to achieve a nice page design without resorting to GWT (the backend is made in java)

For my login screen I copied this [example](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/signin.html). Now I want to mark an error, for instance, that the username was left empty. So I was wondering what is the procedure in the Bootstrap framework for this. Or maybe if there are examples showing the form with error.

I'm not sure if the idea is to show the error message inside the input element with a red color, or to show it below the input element, or maybe with a popup?

Comment: Checkout jquery validate. it is fairly simple. http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Answer (score 348, accepted):

**(UPDATED with examples for Bootstrap v4, v3 and v3)**

Examples of forms with validation classes for the past few major versions of Bootstrap.

**Bootstrap v4**

See the [live version](https://codepen.io/jonschlinkert/pen/rGOorB) on codepen

[image: bootstrap v4 form validation]

```html
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="inputEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label text-success">Email</label>
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input type="email" class="form-control is-valid" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label text-danger">Password</label>
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input type="password" class="form-control is-invalid" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <small id="passwordHelp" class="text-danger">
          Must be 8-20 characters long.
        </small>      
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

**Bootstrap v3**

See the [live version](https://codepen.io/jonschlinkert/pen/jGbXJJ) on codepen

[image: bootstrap v3 form validation]

```html
<form role="form">
  <div class="form-group has-warning">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputWarning">Input with warning</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputWarning">
    <span class="help-block">Something may have gone wrong</span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group has-error">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputError">Input with error</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputError">
    <span class="help-block">Please correct the error</span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group has-info">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputError">Input with info</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputError">
    <span class="help-block">Username is taken</span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group has-success">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputSuccess">Input with success</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSuccess" />
    <span class="help-block">Woohoo!</span>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Bootstrap v2**

See the [live version](http://jsfiddle.net/jonschlinkert/pngWh/12/) on jsfiddle

[image: bootstrap v2 form validation]

The `.error`, `.success`, `.warning` and `.info` classes are appended to the `.control-group`. This is standard Bootstrap markup and styling in v2. Just follow that and you're in good shape. Of course you can go beyond with your own styles to add a popup or "inline flash" if you prefer, but if you follow Bootstrap convention and hang those validation classes on the `.control-group` it will stay consistent and easy to manage (at least since you'll continue to have the benefit of Bootstrap docs and examples)

```html
  <form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="control-group warning">
      <label class="control-label" for="inputWarning">Input with warning</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" id="inputWarning">
        <span class="help-inline">Something may have gone wrong</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group error">
      <label class="control-label" for="inputError">Input with error</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" id="inputError">
        <span class="help-inline">Please correct the error</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group info">
      <label class="control-label" for="inputInfo">Input with info</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" id="inputInfo">
        <span class="help-inline">Username is taken</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group success">
      <label class="control-label" for="inputSuccess">Input with success</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" id="inputSuccess">
        <span class="help-inline">Woohoo!</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Note that with [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms), you have to change `control-group` to `form-group`, add `form-control` to `<input>` elements, `help-inline` to `help-block`, and `warning` to `has-warning`.

Comment: @JimStewart thank you! great to know. I'll update as soon as I have a chance

Comment: this is still working if you follow the comments, but this Eliminates your own label and id.

Comment: It has been changed in Bootstrap V3,

Comment: Bootstrap 3 uses different classes such as has-error. Pleaserefer http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: as mentionned  in bootstrap3 documentation : Bootstrap includes validation styles for error, warning, and success states on form controls. To use, add .has-warning, .has-error, or .has-success to the parent element. Any .control-label, .form-control, and .help-block within that element

Comment: Unfortunately Bootstrap 3 does not support something like `.has-info` class.

Comment: Your link leads to jsFiddle that no longer work. It's there but shows no styling nor validation effects on my screen.

Comment: Would be nice to see example for Bootstrap v5

Answer (score 148):

**Bootstrap V3**:

[Official Doc Link 1](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation)
[Official Doc Link 2](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-help-text)

```
<div class="form-group has-success">
  <label class="control-label" for="inputSuccess">Input with success</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSuccess" />
  <span class="help-block">Woohoo!</span>
</div>
<div class="form-group has-warning">
  <label class="control-label" for="inputWarning">Input with warning</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputWarning">
  <span class="help-block">Something may have gone wrong</span>
</div>
<div class="form-group has-error">
  <label class="control-label" for="inputError">Input with error</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputError">
  <span class="help-block">Please correct the error</span>
</div>
```

Comment: It's great to have a v3 answer, but it doesn't include error messages.

Comment: Thanks @Dave but your suggestion was rejected by others, I updated the answer.

Comment: Your demo link doesn't display the code you posted.

Comment: Thanks @ayjay for pointing this out, unfortunately they have separate documents for adding help blocks. Updated the answer.

Comment: How to make input and .help-block inline ?

Comment: @fsasvari use grid system like this:

<div class="form-group has-success"> <span class="col-sm-12">
<label class="control-label" for="inputSuccess1">Input with success</label>
</span> <span class="col-sm-6">
<input type="text" aria-describedby="helpBlock2" id="inputSuccess1" class="form-control">
</span> <span class="col-sm-6">
<span id="helpBlock2" class="help-block">A block of help text that breaks onto a new line.</span>
</span> </div>

Answer (score 27):

One can also use the following class while using bootstrap modal class (v 3.3.7) ... help-inline and help-block did not work in modal.

```
<span class="error text-danger">Some Errors related to something</span>
```

Output looks like something below:

[image: Example of error text in modal]

Answer (score 4):

**Bootstrap V3:**

Once i was searching for laravel features then i got to know this amazing form validation. Later on, i amended glyphicon icon features. Now, it looks great.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="form-group has-error has-feedback">
    <input id="enter email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Enter email" class="form-control ">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></span>       
    <span class="help-block"><p>The Email field is required.</p></span>                                        
</div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>

<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="form-group has-error has-feedback">
    <input id="account_holder_name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" class="form-control ">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></span>                                            
    <span class="help-block"><p>The Name field is required.</p></span>                                        
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="form-group has-error has-feedback">
 <input id="check_np" name="check_no" type="text" placeholder="Check no" class="form-control ">
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></span>
<span class="help-block"><p>The Check No. field is required.</p></span>                                       
</div>
</div>
```

This is what it looks like:
[image]

**Once i completed it i thought i should implement it in Codeigniter as well. So here is the Codeigniter-3 validation with Bootstrap:**

**Controller**

```
function addData()
{
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','trim|required|valid_email|max_length[128]');
if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
//validation fails. Load your view.
$this->loadViews('Load your view','pass your data to view if any');
}
else
{  
 //validation pass. Your code here.
}
}
```

**View**

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<?php 
 $email_error = (form_error('email') ? 'has-error has-feedback' : '');
 if(!empty($email_error)){
 $emailData = '<span class="help-block">'.form_error('email').'</span>';
 $emailClass = $email_error;
 $emailIcon = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></span>';
}
else{
    $emailClass = $emailIcon = $emailData = '';
 } 
 ?>
<div class="form-group <?= $emailClass ?>">
<input id="enter email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Enter email" class="form-control ">
<?= $emailIcon ?>
<?= $emailData ?>
</div>
</div>
```

**Output:**
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Generally showing the error near where the error occurs is best. i.e. if someone has an error with entering their email, you highlight the email input box.

This article has a couple good examples. 
http://uxdesign.smashingmagazine.com/2011/05/27/getting-started-with-defensive-web-design/

Also twitter bootstrap has some nice styling that helps with that (scroll down to the Validation states section)
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms

Highlighting each input box is a bit more complicated, so the easy way would be to just put an bootstrap alert at the top with details of what the user did wrong. 
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#alerts

Answer (score 1):

For Bootstrap v4 use:
`has-danger` for `form-group` wrapper,
`form-control-danger` for input to show icon (will display ✖ at the end of input),
`form-control-feedback` to message wrapper

Example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="form-group has-danger">
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-danger">
  <div class="form-control-feedback">Not valid :(</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use CSS to show error message only on error.

```
.form-group.has-error .help-block {
    display: block;
}

.form-group .help-block {
    display: none;
}


<div class="form-group has-error">
  <label class="control-label" for="inputError">Input with error</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputError">
  <span class="help-block">Please correct the error</span>
</div>
```