# bootstrap: error text input without control group

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-2

Apparently, the only way to generate a highlighted red text field in Bootstrap 2.3.2 is to create a div with the class `control-group` and `error` around it (see: [Mark error in form using Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14361517/mark-error-in-form-using-bootstrap)).

Isn't there any single Bootstrap class I can assign to the input field to make it red? The documentation only offer the other "solution". Rather, I'd prefer to transform something like this:

```
<div class="control-group error">
  <div class="controls">
    <input type="text" id="inputError">
  </div>
</div>
```

into something like this, much easier to animate or/and maintain:

```
<input type="text" class="someBootstrapErrorClass">
```

Is it possible?

Comment: I don't believe there is a single class to add to an input, how come you don't want to just define a class `form-control-error` and add the CSS, `border-color: #b94a48;-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);`??

Comment: I was just asking if it was possible to do this with Bootstrap, to keep my code maintainable and clean. If not, I'll resort to create my custom CSS class.

Comment: Yea I thought so. An idea is to create more of a global helper class where you could use it in more places than just inputs.