# TextBox change the color after wrong submission

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I try to create bootstrap form which will after wrong submission change the color of the borders to the red. The Problem is that textbox it will always stay in red. Any ideas how can I set the textbox borders red after wrong input. Is there any class in bootstrap that will automatically output that borders in red color after wrong input?

```js
if ($('#TextBoxID').val() == '') {
  $('#TextBoxID').css('border-color', 'red');
} else {
  $('#TextBoxID').css('border-color', ''); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@200;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css">
    
    <div class="sign-up container">
        <h2>Sign Up</h2>
        <p>Please fill this form to create an account.</p>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Username</label>
                <input id="TextBoxID" type="text" name="username" class="form-control" value="">
                <span class=" text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" value="">
                <span class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Confirm Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="confirm_password" class="form-control" value="">
                <span class=" text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset">
            </div>
            <p>Already have an account? <a href="#">Login here</a>.</p>
        </form>
      </div>
      
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mark error in form using Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14361517/mark-error-in-form-using-bootstrap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Problem is that textbox it will always stay in red.

It is because of this line `if ($('#TextBoxID').val() == '')`. You need to check this on form submit

```js
function formSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($('#TextBoxID').val() == '') {
    $('#TextBoxID').css('border-color', 'red');
  } else {
    $('#TextBoxID').css('border-color', '');
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@200;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css">

<div class="sign-up container">
  <h2>Sign Up</h2>
  <p>Please fill this form to create an account.</p>
  <form action="" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Username</label>
      <input id="TextBoxID" type="text" name="username" class="form-control" value="">
      <span class=" text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Password</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" value="">
      <span class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Confirm Password</label>
      <input type="password" name="confirm_password" class="form-control" value="">
      <span class=" text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button onclick="formSubmit(event)" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset"></button>
    </div>
    <p>Already have an account? <a href="#">Login here</a>.</p>
  </form>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```